# Prove that a linear transformation ($\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$) of a basis in $\mathbb R^n$ results in another basis in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $T : \mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a one-to-one linear transformation and $\mathcal{B} = \{b_{1}, b_{2},\ldots, b_{n}\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Show $\mathcal{B}' = \{T(b_{1}), T(b_{2}),\ldots, T(b_{n})\}$ is also a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

I know how to prove linear independence of $\mathcal{B}'$ but having some trouble proving that $\mathcal{B}'$ spans $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Comment: Hint: show $T$ must be invertible, so every vector $v$ is expressible as $v=Tw$, then you can write $w$ with respect to $\cal B$...

Comment: Any collection of $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ is guaranteed to be a basis.

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. In particular, don't just say "I'm having trouble proving this bit", but either give your working or explain why your idea did not work. (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Comment: I have voted to close.  Your claim to "know how to prove linear independence of $\mathcal{B}'$" would bear elaboration.  The extension of that property to spanning the vector space makes use of the finite dimensional property of $\mathbb R^n$, so it would help Readers to respond if you set up the "bookkeeping" for the linear independence property, reassuring them that you are on "the same page".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\dim\mathbb{R}^{n} = n$, it suffices to prove that $\mathcal{B}'$ is LI.

Indeed, this is the case. Once $T$ is injective, its kernel equals $\{0\}$. Thus we have that
\begin{align*}
\alpha_{1}T(b_{1}) + \alpha_{2}T(b_{2}) + \ldots + \alpha_{n}T(b_{n}) = 0 & \Rightarrow T(\alpha_{1}b_{1} + \alpha_{2}b_{2} + \ldots + \alpha_{n}b_{n}) = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow \alpha_{1}b_{1} + \alpha_{2}b_{2} + \ldots + \alpha_{n}b_{n} = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow \alpha_{1} = \alpha_{2} = \ldots = \alpha_{n} = 0
\end{align*}
thence we conclude that $\mathcal{B}'$ is LI, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!